# ASP.NET MVC create a new database record

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I've been learning asp.net mvc 3. So, basically I'm trying to create a new record in database. However, I'm trying to keep a particular record predefined

```
  public ActionResult Create()
    {


        var dc = new ServicesDataContext();

       var model = new Maping();
       var query = (from m in dc.Customers
                    where m.CustomerId == model.CustomerID
                    select m.CustomerId);
       ViewData["CustomerID"] = query.First();
        return View(model);
    } 

    //
    // POST: /Customerservice/Create

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude="CustomerServiceMappingID")] Maping serviceToCreate, FormCollection form)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)

                return View();

       var dc = new ServicesDataContext();
       dc.Mapings.InsertOnSubmit(serviceToCreate);
        try
        {
            dc.SubmitChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }

        try
        {
            var id = Int32.Parse(form["CustomerID"]);
            ViewData["CustomerID"] = id;
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = id });
        }
        catch
        {


            return RedirectToAction("INDEX", "Home");

        }
    }
```

So this is what I did. So, the case is that id value in second action method is what i needed. However the second method gets redirectd to index so viewdata value is lost.And the thing i did in the first crate method is wrong because no value is assigned. So, can u please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use TempData, not ViewData - it will be valid until it is read again. Also why are you adding it into viewdata when it is being passed as a parameter in the RedirectToAction?

Comment: Actullay my index consists of an id as parameter and moreover, I'm using it again in the View but just i found out that I did it wrongly.. Baiscally I need to keep the customer id to the one he clicked in the before page i.e., in a different controller.